# Track yarn's node_modules directory properly in git

Tags: node.js, git, yarnpkg

We've got a weird dependency in our CI that requires our git repo to have a `node_modules` directory (but obviously not the packages in it).

Since git doesn't track empty directories, the way we achieve it is to have a `.gitignore` inside:

```
node_modules/
    .gitignore
```

With the following configuration

```
*
!.gitignore
```

This works, until we re-install our modules using `yarn install`, which will clear everything in the directory, including our `.gitignore` file, messing up the repository.

We can also add something like:

```
node_modules/
    .empty
.gitignore
```

With `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules/*
!/node_modules/.empty
```

But `yarn install` will still remove the file, and any tracking of the `node_modules` directory.

Our question, is there anything that we're missing that can:

1. Allow us to track `node_modules/` in git
2. Won't break whenever we `yarn install`

I'm aware the actual answer is to fix our CI, but that's a bit out of scope for us right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `post install` script that recreates the `.empty` file in `node_modules`.

More specifically, you can have certain scripts added in your `package.json` that run after install is called. In this case:

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "postinstall": "touch node_modules/.empty"
  }
  // ...
}
```

Should make sure there is a file in `node_modules` named `.empty` whenever install has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can prevent deletion of the "placeholder" file if you remove the write permission from the file for the user running `yarn install`. But maybe`yarn install` fails if it cannot clear the directory.